# sql Oracle : Insert a value from another table only when value exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to insert in a table1 a value that comes from another table2 only when value returned from table2 is not null

I would look like to Something like this

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE1
                ( IMG_CODE, NAME, AMOUNT) 
                VALUES ((SELECT MAX(IM_CODE)  FROM IMAGE  WHERE imf_file_name = 'dfkdf4564654.jpg'), 'Meal', 154 )
                WHERE  ((SELECT MAX(IMF_CODE) FROM IMAGE  WHERE imf_file_name = 'dfkdf4564654.jpg') IS NOT NULL);
```

This request raise an error ORA-00933 - "SQL command not properly ended"

Do you know how to do this?

/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a nested subquery:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(IMG_CODE, NAME, AMOUNT) 
SELECT t.IM_CODE, 'Meal', 154
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(IM_CODE) IM_CODE FROM IMAGE  
  WHERE imf_file_name = 'dfkdf4564654.jpg'
) t
WHERE t.IM_CODE IS NOT NULL
```

If `MAX(IM_CODE)` is `NULL` then the row will not be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 ( IMG_CODE, NAME, AMOUNT) 
    SELECT MAX(IM_CODE), 'Meal', 154 
    FROM IMAGE  
    WHERE imf_file_name = 'dfkdf4564654.jpg'
    GROUP BY imf_file_name;
```

This is a little subtle.  If nothing matches your query with no `GROUP BY`, then exactly one row is returned with a `NULL` value.  With a `GROUP BY`, though, only matching groups are returned.  So, if there are no rows, nothing gets inserted.

The advantage to this approach is that it readily extends to multiple file names.